# Mystery: keyboardDidShow Being Called, But It's Not Wired

Tags: iphone

My code is working perfectly to reduce the size of a `UITextView` when the keyboard comes up. The problem is, the signature of the method is

```
- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification*)aNotification
```

but the calling code

```
//[nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
```

is commented out! I have searched low and high using grep and refactor in XCode (to see who else might be calling the method), and nothing comes up. I've checked the nibs just in case. I have tried cleaning targets, etc., but to no avail. If I rename the  method, it does not get called (but this produces no errors). Any ideas as to how/where this method is being "wired?"

Comment: Can you `NSLog` the notification object?

Comment: @JoostK, I checked the NSNotification object, and it's just an instance of `NSConcreteNotification` but nothing interesting there.

Comment: Quite weird then. In what class is this method implemented? I guess a `UIViewController` subclass? I created a test project and implemented this method in the view controller, was not getting called, so it doesn't seem like it's getting called by UIKit then. Have you done a project wide search for `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification`? You say you get no errors when you rename the method, but did you enable `GCC_WARN_UNDECLARED_SELECTOR` in your Build Settings?

Comment: @JoostK thanks, your first question solves the mystery. It's a UITextView subclass. Undocumented method, but anyway: `NSLog(@"What's your deal? %d", [super respondsToSelector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:)]);` prints out a 1, so there's our answer. If you wanted to write this as an answer to the question, I would mark it best answer. Or else I can delete the question....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as it turns out, you implemented `keyboardDidShow:` in a `UITextField` subclass. However, the `UITextField` class itself implements this method as well, so since you've overridden it in your subclass *your* implementation will be getting called, instead of the *UIKit one*. Even though *you* never called it in your code, *UIKit* did it for you.

So that explains why your method was being called, and that renaming the method fixed the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure when it changed, but there is no longer an undocumented `keyboardDidShow:` method in `UITextField`. I've tested this with iOS 8.3.